# Is there any difference between stored procedure and function in oracle and TLSQL?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I would like to know about difference between stored procedure and function in oracle.As a fresher to oracle,can you all help me to know the differences?

Comment: You should have googled first, my friend.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#CIHGHIAE) is very helpful for this sort of thing. Also see the second paragraph at the top of that page: "Typically, you use a procedure to perform an action and a function to compute and return a value", which is common practice, though not enforced.

Answer (score 2):

A function generally returns a single value in Oracle (be it a scalar value, or a single defined object/data-table). A procedure on the other hand can return any number of outputs and does not need to actually have any inputs OR any outputs.

If you need to do JOIN-like behaviour then you'll need to use a function to apply the function against individual rows with varying input. Oracle functions are semantically more graceful than functions - but are harder to optimise and see inside of sometimes.